# select count(1) from tablename where column=column

Tags: sql, oracle, select-query

Question from interview:

- We have table with name = tablename and some column.
- We don't know column type.
- SQL request: `select count(1) from tablename where column=column`

What result does this request return and why?

Comment: You can´t definitly say what the result will be. it will be in the range of `0` - `count(*) x count(*)`.

Comment: why do you think so?

Comment: As you don´t kow anything about the column, nor it´s values this can happen: If all values are `null` the comparison `column=column` wont work (as you´d need `column is null` here) and returns `0` results. If all values are the same you´ll get the result `count(*)`. And as you don´t have the information about the data stored here you´d be somewhere in this range. Edit: sorry, my bad the upper end will just be `count(*)`. So you could say it returns the count for `not null`values in this column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This returns the number of rows where `column` is not null, because `NULL = NULL` yields `UNKNOWN` which evaluates to `false` in the condition. For all other values `column = column` is true.

Answer (score 3):

It's depend from data type. In most case it returns count() of not null columns. 
But for example.

```
create table test_abc(column_name blob);
select count(1) from test_abc where column_name = column_name;
```

`ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got BLOB`

Answer (score 1):

Something "strage" could happen:

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> create table clobTab( c clob);

Table created.

SQL> select count(1) from clobTab where c=c;
select count(1) from clobTab where c=c
                                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will return count with field name (No column name) when column = column is true

else return 0 when column= column is false.